# The code formatted by Prettier is being flagged as non-compliant

Tags: eslint, prettier, typescript-eslint

I use ESLint and Prettier to automatically format TypeScript code, but the formatted code is still being flagged as not compliant with Prettier's rules.

My eslint config:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: { browser: true, es2020: true },
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      'typescript': {}
    }
  },
  extends: [
    'prettier',
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module',
    project: true,
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
  },
  plugins: ['react-refresh', 'prettier'],
  rules: {
    'max-len': ['error', { code: 120 }],
    'prettier/prettier': [
      'error',
      {
        printWidth: 120,
        tabWidth: 2,
        useTabs: false,
        semi: false,
        singleQuote: true,
        quoteProps: 'as-needed',
        jsxSingleQuote: false,
        trailingComma: 'all',
        bracketSpacing: true,
        bracketSameLine: false,
        jsxBracketSameLine: false,
        arrowParens: 'avoid',
        requirePragma: false,
        insertPragma: false,
        proseWrap: 'preserve',
        htmlWhitespaceSensitivity: 'ignore',
        endOfLine: 'lf',
        singleAttributePerLine: true,
      }
    ],
    'no-confusing-arrow': 'off',
    'arrow-body-style': 'off',
    'prefer-arrow-callback': 'off',
  },
}
```

One of my code is like:

```
type BasicDataStructureType = 'Integer' | 'Float' | 'Double' | 'Enumeration' | 'Boolean' | 'Array' | 'Struct'
```

Prettier format it into:

```
type BasicDataStructureType =
  | 'Integer'
  | 'Float'
  | 'Double'
  | 'Enumeration'
  | 'Boolean'
  | 'Array'
  | 'Struct'
```

The formated code is flagged: Replace `⏎··|·'Integer'⏎··|·'Float'⏎··|·'Double'⏎··|·'Enumeration'⏎··|·'Boolean'⏎··|·'Array'⏎·` with `·'Integer'·|·'Float'·|·'Double'·|·'Enumeration'·|·'Boolean'·|·'Array'`

Another formatted non-compliant code is:

```
const Api = {
  getDataStructureVersions: (param: { name: string; namespaceId: number }) =>
    request({ url: `/struct/version/list?${queryString.stringify(param)}`, method: 'GET' }),
}
```

It is flagged as: Delete `⏎···`

Is my eslint or prettier not configured properly? Can someone help me solve this issue? Otherwise, I'll have to remove Prettier.

Answer (score 1):

OK，I solved myself.
I use Prettier vscode plugin instead of eslint-plugin-prettier.
But I still don't know why eslint-plugin-prettier doesn't work around with my prettier config. As long as I set printWidth to 105 or set singleAttributePerLine to true, my code was flagged as not compliant.